# Do RegExps made by expression literals share a single instance?

Tags: javascript, regex, instance, literals, ecmascript-3

The following snippet of code (from Crockford's *Javascript: The Good Parts*) demonstrates that RegExp objects made by regular expression literals share a single instance:

```
function make_a_matcher( ) {
    return /a/gi;
}

var x = make_a_matcher( );
var y = make_a_matcher( );

// Beware: x and y are the same object!

x.lastIndex = 10;

document.writeln(y.lastIndex); // 10
```

**Question**: Is this the same with any other literals?  I tried modifying the code above to work with the string `"string"`, but got a bunch of errors.

Comment: `x` and `y` are most certainly **not** the same object. That `document.writeln()` will not do what you say it does.

Comment: Can't repro. Not in Chrome, Firefox or Safari.

Comment: @FelixKling: Get an older browser :-)

Comment: @Pointy: It could actually happen a long time ago… My hunch to look at ES3 was correct

Answer (score 5):

No, they are not shared. From the [spec on *Regular Expression Literals*](http://es5.github.io/#x7.8.5):

> A regular expression literal is an input element that is converted to a RegExp object (see 15.10) **each time the literal is evaluated**. Two regular expression literals in a program evaluate to regular expression objects that never compare as === to each other even if the two literals' contents are identical.

However, this changed with ES5. [Old ECMAScript 3](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.8.5) had a different behavior:

> A regular expression literal is an input element that is converted to a RegExp object (section 15.10) **when it is scanned**. The object is created before evaluation of the containing program or function begins. Evaluation of the literal produces a reference to that object; it does not create a new object. Two regular expression literals in a program evaluate to regular expression objects that never compare as === to each other even if the two literals' contents are identical.

This was [supposed to share the compilation result](https://whereswalden.com/2010/01/15/more-es5-incompatible-changes-regular-expressions-now-evaluate-to-a-new-object-not-the-same-object-each-time-theyre-encountered/) of the regex engine across evaluations, but obviously led to [buggy progams](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3747776/1048572).

You should throw your book away and get a newer edition.

Comment: I also had the feeling that this was a behavior of older browsers. But the question lacked context. Good find though :)